# Best way to structure C code where malloc used inside a function but free in calling function

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a function which populates dynamic arrays  based on contents of a binary file.
I am using `malloc` to size the array of strings inside the function, then return the pointer and size information back to the calling function.  Since it is an array of strings I am using an array of pointers, so calling `malloc` for the array pointer, then `malloc` for each member.

i.e. in my function I have this code block.  The function returns `p_count` and `p_tokens` to the caller.

```
    // Allocate memory:
    *p_tokens = malloc(*p_count * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)*p_count; i++) {
        (*p_tokens)[i] = malloc(TOKEN_LENGTH);
    }
```

This makes use of `free` from calling code necessary, but of course gets a bit messy.  What is the best way to handle this scenario?  Should I make a separate function to free all pointers generated within my original function?  Should I just deal with a cluster of free loops at the end of my calling code, or am I going about the whole thing incorrectly?

Comment: `(*p_tokens)[i] = malloc(TOKEN_LENGTH);` -->> `p_tokens[i] = malloc(TOKEN_LENGTH);`

Comment: I think that isnt the same thing, right?  p_tokens is a pointer to the array pointer, i,e, *p_tokens is my array, not p_tokens.  The code works as intended - the question was a stylistic one about how to free in calling function.

Comment: Maybe (probably)  you are right! But why should we guess/infer the types of your variables?

Comment: I think its pretty explicit from the line before the for loop.  I'll aim to be more explicit.

Comment: In that case you are a three-star programmer, seeking help.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* make sure the `malloc()`s are paired with the `free()`s. Where you write them is quite irrelevant, the really important point is that the code is structured so that it is easy to check (i.e., hard(er) to get wrong) that they do balance. For example, around the idea of "create (and allocate), use, consume (and free)".

Look for debugging packages, there are instrumented libraries that check specifically for memory management bugs.

Another way to handle this (at some performance cost) is to use some garbage collecting library, like the [Boehm garbage collector](https://www.hboehm.info/gc) for C and C++ (a detailed example is given in [*"Garbage Collection in C Programs"*](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6679) by Insolvible,Linux Journal, aug 2003). The garbage collector is available on most Linux distributions, being open source it can be built and installed on most systems.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a `free_token_array(token *array, size_t count)` that would free the tokens and the array in the same module as your allocation function makes sense. This way you can easily keep them in sync if you change allocation strategies.

Also note that you should avoid casting `*p_count` in the allocation loop, just write:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *p_count; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should control the status of your "strings" somewhere. Structure of: pointers + flags for existence + flags for initialization + flags for access.

```
struct arrstring {
    p_string * Strings;
    // flags of allocation
    p_exist * ExistFlag;
    // flags tracking initialization with values
    p_init * InitStrings;
    // flags allowing access/lock
    p_access * AccessF;
    p_mutex * LockStrings;
}
```

This way you could create all strings with one call to 'calloc()', but initialize them later.

PS.

Here at *sizeof(char *)* you take size of pointer, I don't know your intentions but this looks like a misunderstanding. You can take ahead the maximum size of your string like 512 byte, and allocate it with malloc(MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char)).

Also using 'char' for strings is kind of deprecated feature. Good for testing purposes, but there is actual characters today, and 'char' is used as only acronym of 'byte' (it works because UTF-8 is widely accepted and smallest UTF-8 sized values picked coincidentally with ASCII).

PS2. The C17 standard is confirming that "uchar.h" and "wchar.h" are widely accepted and supported by C environments. So users could deal with characters accordingly if it goes beyond 'char' type.

PS3. Well, about the C standards about characters. C always were "silent" when it comes to characters and various systems decide it differently. So the way how C works with strings is named as "C strings" to distinguish it. In "C strings" the length of strings is always measured in "char" or "wchar_t" which are fixed size, *even if the string itself is variable-width encoded*, this could lead to problems because long width characters will be interpreted as few characters. But the size of "char" will always be fixed itself, on some machines it was 6 bit, on some machines it was 12 bit. Now it is mostly 8 bit, so most of the times programmers are referring to it as "integer type", and there is common ground when programmers suppose that char=byte. Well it reflects by itself the evolution of term of "byte" itself.

Comment: The last 2 paragraphs are misinformation. `char` is and always has been the right type for textual data. The elements of a `char` array don't necessarily represent whole characters (in any modern setting, they should be UTF-8 code units) but this doesn't change that it's the right type. `wchar.h` is mostly a historical mistake and only needed when you do want to try to process individual character identities, and should only be used for processing not storage. In any case these paragraphs are completely OT from OP's question.